Duplicate library warning despite private visibility linking
I have a base library called simple_events that is created as a static library via cmake. I have a dependent library called simple_server that depends upon simple_events in order to fire lifecycle events on key methods. simple_server links privately against simple_events.
I have a simple_client_application that uses simple_server (and [thus] simple_events) to create a simple client application that is the amalgamation of the library functionalities.
These are all separate projects that have their own distinct builds, as my intention is to build modular, re-useable libraries for my projects.
Below, you will find the relevant CMakeLists.txt snippets of the projects mentioned:
simple_events/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(simple_events STATIC simple_events.cpp)
# some installation instructions

simple_server/CMakeLists.txt
find_package(SimpleEvents REQUIRED) # works as expected
add_library(simple_server STATIC simple_server.cpp simple_connection.cpp connection_abort.cpp connection_start.cpp connection_read.cpp connection_write.cpp server_start.cpp server_abort.cpp server_accept.cpp)
[...]
target_link_libraries(simple_server
  PRIVATE Simple::simple_events
)
[...]

simple_application/CMakeLists.txt
find_package(SimpleEvents REQUIRED)
find_package(SimpleServer REQUIRED)
add_executable(simple_app ${APP_SOURCES})
[...]
target_link_libraries(simple_app PUBLIC Simple::simple_events Simple::simple_server)
[...]

When I build simple_app, I get a ld linker warning: ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '/usr/local/lib/libsimple_events.a'.
My understanding is that because simple_server links privately against simple_events, it would not be linked nor accessible to simple_app transitively. So, simple_app also finds and links against simple_events. However, it seems that somewhere along the way ld is finding duplicate link instructions against simple_events and I want to know why and how to fix it.
I, of course, rubber ducked with GPT but it kept asking me to assure that simple_server was PRIVATELY linking against simple_events, which was just not instilling in me confidence that it understood a solution.
I'm thinking that maybe because simple_server is being built as a static library that it includes all of the symbols of simple_events and because simple_app also links against simple_events the symbols are being duplicated in the final binary? ... but this is just a guess.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, even a link. Thank you.

What is simple_server? A shared library?

@3CxEZiVlQ Thanks for your question. I've updated the description to reflect the answer, but -- in short -- it's a static library.

If simple_server is a static library then target_link_libraries(simple_server PRIVATE Simple::simple_events) is wrong. Dependencies should be in the public interface of the target simple_server.

You would need something like libtool, this SO question may interest you : How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one?.

@3CxEZiVlQ why is it wrong?

@PepijnKramer merging the libraries would likely turn a duplicate library warning into a duplicate symbol error

@3CxEZiVlQ: The linkage target_link_libraries(simple_server PRIVATE Simple::simple_events) could be correct even in case of simple_server being a static library. Even with PRIVATE keyword a "physical" linkage with the library file, represented by a Simple::simple_events  target, will be propagated to the consumer of simple_server target. This is how CMake works.

Thanks for all of your continued responses. So what you're saying @Tsyvarev is that even though simple_server privately links against simple_events, the link interface of simple_server is still listing simple_events as a dependency to the consuming application, and this is just how CMake works. Thank you. I'll look into INTERFACE libraries and see if that will work for my needs. Initial research seems to point to yes. Thank you!

@Avienneau: Most compilers perfectly work with the library which is repeated in the command line. And such duplication is not resulted in duplication of symbols in the resulted executable. Since you get the warning "ignoring duplicate libraries", then problem could be specific to the compiler you use. You are better to include into the question post details about that side.
